# How to save client side rendered svg graphic as svg file?

Tags: svg, client-side, filesaver.js, jsxgraph

There are several javascript libraries which render svg images on the client side.

**Example**

[JSXGraph](https://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/about/index.html)

**Screenshot**

[image]

It's easy to make a screenshot of the svg image but is it possible to download the image as a svg file from the client side?

**A possible workaround**

[On the server side it is possible](https://jsxgraph.org/wp/2012/11/02/howto-export-jsxgraph-constructions/), so maybe by downloading the page and modifying the source code (add `var svg = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(board.renderer.svgRoot);` and [FileSaverJS](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)) it can be done?! Isn't there an easier solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(board.renderer.svgRoot);` returns the SVG code. Alternatively, JSXGraph offers the method `board.renderer.dumpToDataURI(ignoreTexts)` which returns a base64 encoded data URI of the SVG code. If called with the parameter ignoreTexts==false, those JSXGraph elements which are displayed as HTML elements, like some texts, will be enclosed in a `foreignObject` tag in the SVG.

So, if you want to use `board.renderer.dumpToDataURI` to get SVG source code, you have to base64 decode it like this:

```
atob(board.renderer.dumpToDataURI(false).split(',')[1]);
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/s9ch1e73/1/ for a working example.

If you just want to copy the SVG code from a working example, you can paste the above code into the JavaScript console of the browser and copy the output.